# Onclick on Div is not working on Angular - 9

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, onclick

Here is my HTML

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="150px">
 <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let tile of tiles;index as j;"
     [colspan]="tile.cols"
     [rowspan]="tile.rows"
     >
   <div (onclick)="openbox();" style="z-index: 2">
                                       
          {{tile.text}}<br>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1027&q=80" height="200px" width="260px">
   </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Ts

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
...
 openbox(){
    console.log('clicked')
  }
...
}
```

Things i tried:

> `style="z-index: 2; position: relative;"`
> Incognito

Browser Chrome Angular-9
**My goal is get the index of clicked mat-grid-tile is there any other way to do this?**
Thankyou

Comment: Listening to click events in angular can be done using (click), not (onclick)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the (click) event. `onClick` doesn't work because the Angular Compiler doesn't recognise it and that goes for all browser events with prefix `on`. If you wan't to use the event in Angular you need to remove the `on`.

```
<div (click)="openbox();" style="z-index: 2">
   ...
</div>
```